# Assigning domain name to AWS ElasticIP

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, dns-hosting, amazon-route53

I'm having trouble registering a domain name (e.g mydomain.co.uk) purchased via Amazon's Route 53. I have an AWS instance which I have set to an elastic IP address (e.g 10.10.10.10) - which I can access the instance via this IP fine. I have the following set up as a hosted zone for the domain in the Route 53 dashboard:

```
A   - mydomain.co.uk, 10.10.10.10 (elastic IP of machine)
NS  - mydomain.co.uk, ns-969.awsdns-57.net 
                      ns-357.awsdns-44.com 
                      ns-1643.awsdns-13.co.uk 
                      ns-1412.awsdns-48.org
SOA - mydomain.co.uk, ns-1412.awsdns-48.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

Where the Name Server values are obtained from the registered domain. Trying to access the domain (in Chrome) returns the error `ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED`.

This is my first time doing anything like this, is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the domain in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the hosted zone, I altered the Name-Server values:

> Where the Name Server values are obtained from the registered domain

Where I needed this to be the **other way around**. The domain needed to point to the Name Servers generated by the hosted zone.

Answer (score 0):

How long did you want between purchasing mydomain and trying this? There is a propagation delay when making DNS changes.

If you've waited several hours and still seeing the issue, do

dig +trace mydomain.co.uk

That should show you where in the chain the problem is occurring.